# How properly use reverse in tests?

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework

There are `SimpleRouter` with `ViewSet`:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet)
```

When i trying to write some tests for get endpoint:
If i use `url = reverse('product-list')`, then i have url **product/** and this is what i want.
But after all product API i want to test **product/pk/** api but i don't find the proper reverse in django rest framework Docs, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse("product-detail", kwargs={"pk": 4})
```